# php not working after installation

Tags: php, apache

I just installed apache2 and php version 7 on my centos OS, i tested the apache server it was working fine  i try check php info by running a script info.php that has the following code in it

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

and this work as expected, now when i try to run other php script all i got was a blank page i tried so many times , i uninstall php 7 and install the lower version but the same problem persist i don't really have an idea why this happen, any help on this will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: does a simple `echo "Hello World";` script work?

Comment: thanks for your reply, echo "hello world "; shows blank page

Comment: I think you have to find someone who you can grant access to your server to solve this issue.

Comment: How about _virtualhosts_ in _apache_, did you config them properly and did you add your hosts to the _etc/hosts_?

Answer (score 0):

Your other php script may have errors. You can find out the error by enabling error reporting in your php script. It can be done by adding following code to the top of your php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```